# why do I get "./exe: free(): Invalid Pointer" error?

Tags: c++, pointers, runtime-error

I'm a system engineering student and I'm working on a assignment from my university. The thing is I'm getting the error mentioned above in one of my programs. The program have to get a text file and extract all the text lines from it, the text file name is passed as an argument on the console, once the text lines are extracted I store them on a static vector declared on the conversacion class, then the persona object has to get the a line from the vector and if it the received line meet certain conditions the persona object will return the received line with the mood, name or age of the persona.

Looks like the error is on the persona class, deleting the last while on the main method makes my program runs perfectly.

the code is as follows:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
int iterador=0;
Conversacion * conversacion=new Conversacion();
Persona * persona1 = new Persona("David",21,"feliz");
Persona * persona2 = new Persona("John",24,"aburrido");

char linea[40];
string nomarchivo;
nomarchivo=argv[1];

ifstream archivo(nomarchivo.c_str());

while(!archivo.eof()){

    archivo.getline(linea, 40);

    string clinea(linea);

    conversacion->getConversacion(clinea);
}
archivo.close();
/**This for is just meant to print the contents of the vector just to check if 
is it ok, and yes it is.**/
for(int i=0; i<(conversacion->getVectorSize()-1); i++){

    cout <<i+1 <<") "<<conversacion->getLinea(i)<< endl;

}
/**Deleting this while makes my program runs perfectly, the error
 seems to be here but don't know what could it be**/
while(iterador<conversacion->getVectorSize()-1){

    cout << persona1->sendResponse(conversacion, iterador)<<endl;

    cout << persona2->sendResponse(conversacion, iterador)<<endl;


}
```

In the conversacion.cpp file

```
Conversacion::Conversacion(){}
Conversacion::~Conversacion(){}

void Conversacion::getConversacion(string lineaIn){

    conversacion.push_back(lineaIn);

}

string Conversacion::getLinea(int iteradorIn){

    return conversacion[iteradorIn];

}

int Conversacion::getVectorSize(){
    return conversacion.size();

}
```

In the persona.cpp file

```
Persona::Persona(string nombreIn, int edadIn, string animoIn){

    nombre=nombreIn;
    edad=edadIn;
    animo=animoIn;

}

Persona::~Persona(){}

string Persona::getNombre(){
    return nombre;
}

int Persona::getEdad(){
    return edad;
}

string Persona::getAnimo(){
    return animo;
}


string Persona::sendResponse(Conversacion * &conversacionIn, int & iteradorIn){
    string mensaje;
    if(conversacionIn->getLinea(iteradorIn).compare("hola")){
        mensaje=conversacionIn->getLinea(iteradorIn).append(conversacionIn->getLinea(iteradorIn+1));
       iteradorIn++;                
       return "hola" + mensaje;




    }else if(conversacionIn->getLinea(iteradorIn).compare("y como estas?")==0){
        mensaje=conversacionIn->getLinea(iteradorIn);
        iteradorIn++;           
        return animo + mensaje;



    }else if(conversacionIn->getLinea(iteradorIn).compare("cuantos años tienes?")==0){
        mensaje=conversacionIn->getLinea(iteradorIn);
        stringstream edadc;
        string stredad;
        edadc << edad;
        stredad=edadc.str();

        iteradorIn++;
        return stredad+ mensaje;



    }else if(conversacionIn->getLinea(iteradorIn).compare("chao")==0){
        iteradorIn++;
        return "chao";


    }

}
```

this is the error im getting on the console:

```
Error in `./exe': free(): invalid pointer: 0x00007ffefe07dbf0 ***

======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x777e5)[0x7fb724f1b7e5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x7fe0a)[0x7fb724f23e0a]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(cfree+0x4c)[0x7fb724f2798c]
./exe[0x402bb1]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7fb724ec4830]
./exe[0x401779]
```

Comment: One odd thing is that in `sendResponse` you have `iteradorIn++;` *after* the `return` statement. This means that the increment never happens, because you have already returned to the calling function.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: @BoPersson You're right, already correct my mistake

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your code, you're doing something illegal and undefined (dereferencing a garbage pointer, indexing off the end of an array, accessing something after it is deleted or destroyed, deleting something that wasn't created with new, or deleting something twice).  To figure out what is going wrong where, the best tool is probably [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).

Answer (score 0):

I already fix it, the `sendResponse` method was lacking of an `else` condition so it couldn't enter a case where no condition was meet and couldn't return anything causing that weird error.